# ie Edge svg text fill render error

Tags: svg, vue.js, microsoft-edge, fill

I'm new in SVG. When I use Vue.js to change the SVG's  fill attribute. It's position render error! but render correctly in the other browser!  I try to google and search in stackoverflow,but there is not solution to solve the issue.  thx.

```
<svg width="8.4em" height="2.2em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 315 70">
  <g>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" :fill="data.fill">
  </g>
</svg>
```

In IE edge

- the issue link(PS: my reputation is under 10,so paste the link :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i7tf.png

but it's ok on IE10,IE11

and the demo url is :  http://codepen.io/WangXiZhu/pen/PpxBWW

Comment: What IE version ?

Comment: it is MicroSoft Edge , which on  window10 installed on virtual machine of  my mac,then I found it's ok on IE10 and IE11.